# ImageView and NSString Variables Reset after Switching Views

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, background, uiimageview

I am designing an iPhone program where it is possible to press a 'Customize' Rounded Rect Button in one view that displays a different view (I used the modal connection on the built-in storyboard to switch between the views), from which it is possible to customize the background on the first view.  The Customize screen (second screen) has several buttons to choose the background that use the following code:

**ViewController.h:**

```
@interface{
...
IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImageTest;

...

}

...

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *backgroundImageName;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImageTest;

...
```

**ViewController.m:**

```
- (IBAction)setJungleBackground:(id)sender {

backgroundImageName=@"jungle.png";

backgroundImageTest.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"jungle.png"];
}

- (IBAction)setArcticBackground:(id)sender {

backgroundImageName=@"arctic.png";

backgroundImageTest.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"arctic.png"];
}
```

for each of the possible backgrounds.

Also in ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

if(!notFirstTime){

    notFirstTime=YES;

    ...

    backgroundImageName=@"white.png";

}

...

backgroundImageTest.image=[UIImage imageNamed:backgroundImageName];

...

[super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Each time the views are switched, the firstTime boolean resets to NO, and the background remains the default background (@"white.png").  If I replace @"white.png" with @"jungle.png", the background works, but cannot switch to any other background.

I use one ViewController for both of the views.  It seems to have worked great so far, except for this one small problem.  Should I use multiple ViewControllers?  I am not sure under what circumstances I should do so.

Also, I'm not sure if I should use retain or strong in the property declaration of variables.

I am relatively new to iPhone programming, and any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLoad is called after your view controller is instantiated - it seems you're continuously recreating your view controller instance. Avoid that and afterwards use viewDidAppear.

Comment: That sounds right - how do I avoid creating multiple copies of the View Controller, and what is the difference between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear?  I just started iPhone programming, and frankly I don't know where the ViewController is instantiated.

Comment: @Alekxos it's instantiated when you call `[[MyViewController alloc] init...]`. I already explained what viewDidLoad does - have a look at Apple's docs.

Comment: I moved the viewDidLoad code to viewDidAppear, but nothing has changed.  Could the error possibly be caused by using one controller for two views? I'm not sure how the controller would know which view viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear means.

Comment: @Alekxos as I said, moving your code is not enough in itself - you should make sure the creation of the view controller doesn't occur multiple times, only once.

Comment: How would I do that? I searched for [[MyViewController alloc] init...] in the AppDelegate, but it wasn't there - is there somewhere else it would be? I'm using ARC, if that matters.

Comment: @Alekxos well maybe you're using IB to create your view controller  - in this case I'd rather advise you to create programmatically...